# How to enable a PIN but allow quick access to camera?

Tags: lock-screens, camera

In Android 4.1, when you set the lock screen security to "slide", you can quickly access the camera by sliding left.

Is there a way to get a similar sliding mechanism, but at the same time require a PIN to access the rest of the phone?

Comment: @houbysoft: This applies to Android 4.0.x as well.

Comment: What device do you have? If it's a Sammy, you might want to take a look at the XPosed module [Enable camera on lockscreen](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.enablecameraonlockscreen).

Comment: I do have a Pin on my Motorola G8 power, and I can quickly access the camera or lantern by shaking the phone with the gestures predefined for it (Motorola specific). The same gestures worked for my old G4 phone, but I've never tried for older versions...

Answer (score 1):

This application lets you start the camera app even from a password locked screen. Full disclosure: I developed the app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aeropic.CameraUnlockFree