# How do you skip the PIN to go directly to the camera from the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens, camera

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 (standard, not rooted). I previously had an iPhone, and the feature I miss the most is the ability to go directly to the camera from the lock screen without having to type in my PIN. How do I do this on Android?

I know that there are at least two or three questions asking pretty much the same question. Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation to comment on those answers to explain why they don't help me:

- [Is it possible to use the camera without unlocking first?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14942/is-it-possible-to-use-the-camera-without-unlocking-first):
- [How to enable a PIN but allow quick access to camera?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/how-to-enable-a-pin-but-allow-quick-access-to-camera)

For both of these posts, the accepted answers recommend WidgetLocker, but the persons who gave the answers had apparently never tried it themselves. I've tried at least five different free lock screen apps, but none of them solve my problem--they all still require a PIN to use the camera. <s>I haven't tried WidgetLocker, but I'm not going to pay for an app that I'm not sure will work, especially when all the others I've tried don't work. Does anyone know for sure that WidgetLocker resolves this problem?</s> I also bought and tried WidgetLocker, but it doesn't support PINs at all, and so it is **not** a solution to this problem.

- [How to use camera without unlocking phone? (Jelly Bean on S3)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32029/how-to-use-camera-without-unlocking-phone-jelly-bean-on-s3):

This answer suggests using Samsung's built in motion. I tried this, and it still requires the PIN to access the camera. This answer doesn't resolve the issue. I'm certainly willing to pay for an app that solves this issue, but I don't need any other lock screen features--I just want rapid access to my camera. Also, I would prefer not to root my phone just for this, but if there is a solution via rooting, I would seriously consider it.

Can anyone please suggest an answer that really works?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can get a refund in the Play Store up to 15 minutes after your purchase.

Comment: Do you have any Device Administrators enabled?   I wonder if it's possible for them to force the PIN requirement.

Comment: @TomG Even if you have Device Administrators, you CAN bypass the PIN entry on some configurations. For example, my lockscreen on Sony Xperia Z shows a camera shortcut above the PIN entry keypad.

Comment: @TomG, I have no idea what Device Administrators are. Could you please explain what they are and how they could resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Ochado, Device Administrators can impose security policies on a device; I was thinking that it's possible that a policy requiring a PIN may make it impossible to launch any app without the PIN.   If you have a device administrator enabled (System Settings->Security & Screen Lock -> Device Administrators on my phone), you may be stuck if (for example) your corporate email access requires the policy.  More info on device admins is on the [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: Thanks, @TomG. I looked into it, and I confirmed that there is no device administrator restricting my device.

Comment: Thanks, @Al Everett, for the tip on the 15-minute reimbursement window. Unfortunately, that wasn't enough time for me to test and verify that WidgetLocker does not work :-(. I've edited my question to mention that I unsuccessfully tried WidgetLocker.

Comment: @Ochado: That is one of the features I miss from iPhone. I really thought there will be some way to get this, but so far I haven't found any.

Comment: Update: I now use an LG G3 with Android 5 (now upgrade to Android 6) which has the iPhone-like feature I requested built in, so the problem is moot for me now. However, the answers to this question would probably still be helpful to people with systems that don't have this functionality built in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way in Android to access to the standard Android camera from a password-protected device. However this little application allows to access to a simple camera with a triple press on the power button even when the device is **password** locked...

[Camera Unlock (free)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aeropic.CameraUnlockFree)

[image] [image]

Disclosure: I am the developer of this app

Comment: I've installed the app and I'm currently trying it out. It is rather rough in a number of ways, but based on my extensive searches, it is definitely the closest I've ever seen to what I'm looking for. Thanks! I'll post support issues through the normal support channels for the app.

Comment: Thanks Ochado, I'll try to improve the app. I know it is by now a bit limited, but it starts doing the job ;-)

Comment: @aeropic two things would make your app perfect: (1) use slide screen (like in kitkat) or a buton (like in iphone) to open it. (2) let it simply allow us launch our own [camera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marginz.snap&hl=en) instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by following these steps...   I just did it I have an S3 Rooted, running 4.1.2

- Root your phone
- Install Xposed Framework
- Install the Enable Camera on Lockscreen Module

Comment: Thanks for the root suggestion, but I'm still avoiding rooting for now.

Answer (score 1):

i hav android 4.4.2,just swipe from right to left on screen..u will directly go to camera app without entering the pin.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called "HI screen lock"
This basically turn ur lock scren to iphone lock screen.
So it allows you to use camera without putting password. And also it allows you to use calculator and flashlights witout unlocking it.
Only bad part is that you have to buy full version to change the background to how you want and that it only allows 4 number password.

Comment: Could you please include a link to that app? I cannot find any app with this name at GPlay. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response, but have you actually used the app and confirmed that it really does let you use the camera on a password-protected lock screen, but without entering the password? In my question description, I explained that I have tried many apps that supposedly did this but in fact did not. Please edit your question to say explicity whether or not you have tried it and it really works for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

HI screen lock works sort of.  It can be defeated by resetting the point. This is need because there is no way to clear the register if you type in a wrong pin digit (ie no back/clear button).  To get around this, I have set a Android pin with a 1/2 hour time out.  this pin is functional at boot up.  The downside is that occasionally I have type enter the pin twice.  Acceptable for the time being as a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

GSmart Saga 3 just slide right in lock mode to turn on camera

Comment: I've just tried that on my device after setting up a lockscreen PIN: it still requires the user to enter the PIN in order to access the camera. Have you checked that?